# Lorentz Invariance of the Dirac equation

Tags: quantum-mechanics

My question is more conceptual than mathematical. As a differential equation the Dirac equation is invariant under Lorentz transformations. Conceptually though Lorentz transformations describe a "Classical picture". According to the most "authoritative" interpretation of QM it is unclear or even totally forbidden to think of a path between the two inertial frames. Does this mean that the relative velocity is be interpreted as the expectation value between inertial frames? Or, is it that I just "don't get" quantum mechanics? Which is most likely anyhow!

Fosco

Comment: *"Conceptually though Lorentz transformations describe a "Classical picture"* [citation needed] Nothing about saying "our spacetime is Minkowski space, and hence we need to represent its isometry group on our physical system" is classical or quantum.

Answer (score 2):

You are mixing Lorentz invariance, reference frame and relative motion. In Newtonian mechanics there are also inertial frames and relative velocities. Lorentz invariance only means that the Dirac equation looks the same in any inertial frame obtained by a Lorentz transformation. It is true though that somethings doesn't smell right. The reason being  that the Dirac equation is still "semiclassical", in the sense that it still admits an interpretation in which there is an assumed "macroscopic" observer, not bounded by QM rules.